# SQLAlchemy delete many to many with Association Object

Tags: sqlalchemy, many-to-many

So I have myself a many to many relationship which requires extra data in the association table. As a result, I have used an Association Object.

I can delete the Association Object itself from the DB just fine, but there doesn't seem to be any cascade taking place. I have looked at the documentation and followed it as best I could (I'm somewhat of a beginner here), but the situation as explained there does not seem to apply to my situation entirely (and I can't quite figure out the way to get it to work right).

So I have three classes. Student, CMClass and StudentClass (this being the Association Object):

```python
class Student(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Students'
    
    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column('NAME', String(50), unique=True)
    CMClasses = relationship("StudentClass", back_populates="Student", secondary="StudentClasses", cascade="all, delete")
    
class CMClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Classes"
    
    id = Column('ID', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = Column('NAME', String(50), unique=True)
    classDate = Column('CLASS_DATE', DateTime, nullable=True)
    Students = relationship("StudentClass", back_populates="CMClass", secondary="StudentClasses")
    
class StudentClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'StudentClasses'
    student_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Students.ID', ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)       
    CMClass_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Classes.ID', ondelete="CASCADE"), primary_key=True)
    attended = Column(Boolean)
    Student = relationship("Student", back_populates="CMClasses")
    CMClass = relationship("CMClass", back_populates="Students")
```

It all seems to work rather well honestly, except for the cascade delete. I've played around with the 'relationship' part of the two sub classes (Student and CMClass). I think that's where the issue lies, but honestly I'm just not sure how to set it up. The examples just use an association table, which seems to work a little differently from an association object.

Comment: You can specify 'cascade' options also on the [`relationship()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship).

Those you specified on the `ForeignKey` are only for the DDL generation.

Comment: Also not sure what you expect to cascade. If a student drops a course we can safely assume that the student and the course still exist. IOW, if I simply drop "Programming 101" that does not mean that either "Programming 101" (the course) or *I* (the student) disappear.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can you explain what you delete, and what you expect to cascade with an example?